# Verilog error for 2d array declaration

Tags: verilog, multidimensional-array

- I wrote this code for register file in verilog.
- There is error in 2d array declaration of data that it is not declared.
- I am using ModelSim Altera 10.1d

  ```
  model RegFile(clk,reset,ReadReg1,ReadReg2,WriteData,WriteReg,RegWrite,ReadData1,ReadData2);

  input clk,reset,RegWrite;
  input [1:0] ReadReg1,ReadReg2,WriteReg;
  input [31:0] WriteData;
  output [31:0] ReadData1,ReadData2;
  reg [31:0] d,q1,q2,q3,q4,q;
  reg [3:0] decoutp;
  reg clkwrite,
  reg [31:0] data [3:0];
  reg [31:0] ReadData1,ReadData2;

  initial
  begin
  d = 32'h00000000;
  data[0] = 32'd101;
  data[1] = 32'd234;
  data[2] = 32'd260;
  data[3] = 32'd120;
  end

  always@(posedge clk)
  begin
  if(reset)
  begin
  reg32bit(q1,d,clk,reset);
  reg32bit(q2,d,clk,reset);
  reg32bit(q3,d,clk,reset);
  reg32bit(q4,d,clk,reset);
  end

  else
  begin
  //Write
  decoder2_4(decoutp,WriteReg);
  clockgate(clkwrite,RegWrite,clk,decoutp);
  reg32bit(q,WriteData,clkwrite,reset);

  //Read
  if(ReadReg1 == 2'b00) ReadData1 = data[0];
  else if(ReadReg1 == 2'b01) ReadData1 = data[1];
  else if(ReadReg1 == 2'b10) ReadData1 = data[2];
  else ReadData1 = data[3];

  if(ReadReg2 == 2'b00) ReadData2 = data[0];
  else if(ReadReg2 == 2'b01) ReadData2 = data[1];
  else if(ReadReg2 == 2'b10) ReadData2 = data[2];
  else ReadData2 = data[3];

  end
  end

  endmodule
  ```
- Error -

  (1)v(9): near "reg": syntax error, unexpected reg, expecting IDENTIFIER or
    TYPE_IDENTIFIER

  (2)v(15): (vlog-2730) Undefined variable: 'data'.

Comment: Separate Error: modules cannot be instantiated inside always blocks. `reg32bit`, `decoder2_4`, and `clockgate` don't look like functions or 0-time tasks.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have a typo.  There's a comma after the clkwrite declaration.

Answer (score 0):

insert a semicolon after the `clkwrite`.
like this

```
 reg clkwrite; 
reg [31:0] data [3:0];
```

and remove the instantiation of submodule inside the always block

Answer (score -1):

The given array syntax is supported in SystemVerilog .sv
reg [31:0] data [3:0];